# Datetime series property

Tags: pandas, datetime

Could you help me on this issue please?

I am recently upgraded my pandas to version 1.0.0 and one of my code stopped working. More specifically, I used to get the weekday_name property from the date using

> > s.dt.weekday_name

Now, since pandas upgraded, I got this error:
AttributeError: 'DatetimeProperties' object has no attribute 'weekday_name'

I check the document and it seemed this property change to 'day_name' so I tried:

> > s.dt.day_name

However, the output doesn't turn out as expected.

`bound method PandasDelegate._add_delegate_accessors.<locals>._create_delegator_method.<locals>.f of <pandas.core.indexes.accessors.DatetimeProperties object at 0x0000021670C93748`

I would much appreciated if you could let me know the workaround.

Example to reproduce:
`s = pd.date_range('2016-12-31', '2017-01-08', freq='D').to_series()`
`s.dt.weekday_name`
`s.dt.day_name`

Comment: just run as `s.dt.day_name()` since this is a method now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Series.dt.day_name` is implemented as a method, not an attribute. As such you need to call it with `()`

```
s.dt.day_name()
#2016-12-31     Saturday
#2017-01-01       Sunday
#2017-01-02       Monday
#2017-01-03      Tuesday
#2017-01-04    Wednesday
#2017-01-05     Thursday
#2017-01-06       Friday
#2017-01-07     Saturday
#2017-01-08       Sunday
#Freq: D, dtype: object
```

Unlike the old, `Series.dt.weekday_name` attribute, you can now pass arguments which allow you to change the language.

```
s.dt.day_name('Danish')
#2016-12-31     Lørdag
#2017-01-01     Søndag
#2017-01-02     Mandag
#2017-01-03    Tirsdag
#2017-01-04     Onsdag
#2017-01-05    Torsdag
#2017-01-06     Fredag
#2017-01-07     Lørdag
#2017-01-08     Søndag
#Freq: D, dtype: object
```